# Converting an unprojected coordinate system to a projected one in QGIS 3.10 without ruining data

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am new to GIS and I think I may have posted on the wrong website:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595452/how-to-convert-an-uprojected-coordinate-system-to-a-projected-one-in-qgis-3-10-w

I created a map in `QGIS 3.10` using a non-projected CRS (`WGS84 EPSG:4326`). I want to display it in `3D Map View`, but QGIS tells me that `3Dview` does not support uprojected CRS, and I have to switch to a projected CRS. *But when I do that, distances get distorted*.

I am writing a novel and this is the **map of a fictional, island-like location (a microcosm, a metaphor for earth)**. It is about 5kms x 10kms, currently placed exactly on the **South Pole** (I know, probably the root of my trouble).

I guess that's where I made a huge blunder. I did not know that QGIS does not support unprojected CRS for `3Dview`. If I knew, I would have created everything using a projected CRS and would have placed my imaginary map somewhere less symbolic and more compatible with projected systems. Now, I have created so much data that it is impossible to start anew (the picture shows only a small portion of that data).

I switched to a projected CRS for both *the layers* and *the project*, but (obviously) the distances shrank almost 100,000 times. Using some systems (E.g. `WGS84/World Mercator EPSG:3395`) did not distort the map. The proportions remained fine, but distances got distorted and instead of 5km, I got 5cm! (That's not a microcosm for humans, it's for ants). Some (E.g. `ESRI:102037 - South_Pole_Orthographic`) distorted both.

I want to convert my unprojected CRS to a projected one, without distorting proportions or distances. Since this is a fictional place, the location of the map, real coordinates, and the CRS are **NOT** important. As long as the shape and distances remain intact, any location, CRS, etc. will do.

How do I do the conversion with the least hassle?

[image: Image of Crystalia]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109945/discussion-on-question-by-blackcanopus-converting-an-unprojected-coordinate-syst).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after discussion, the workaround here was to set the crs to a projected one, then scale everything up by 110,000 using GRASS's v.transform for all vector layers.

For the raster layer, it was re-georeferenced against a few reference points from the fresh vector layers.